# nth-child not rendering in Dreamweaver

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

So I have a newsBox with float left that contains a picture, title and small text that contains small segments of news. I have 2 news boxes in every row, and I want every 1st newsBox to have an extra margin-right with 20px.

I have used .newsBox:nth-child(odd) { margin-right:20px; } in the css, and it works fine in Chrome but doesn't render in Dreamweaver CS6.

Is this not an officially supported rule? Or there is another more "clean" way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please post de `HTML`?

Comment: do you mean that it does not render in the design view of dreamweaver? There is no good support for the design view in dreamweaver so things tend to skip around, look weird or in your case just not render at all. I would say just worry about it rendering in the browser and not in your IDE.

Comment: Ok thanks! ^^ Yes I ment in design view it doesn't render as it should. I guess I'll just ignore it and continue testing in Chrome.

Comment: First thing, People see your website on their desired browser not on your IDE. Second thing, Make websites `cross browser` compatible not `cross IDE` compatible. Third thing, Dreamweaver leaves these *type of* advanced CSS or some CSS3 features and donot render them.

Comment: please let us know if the solution provided below helped you and if so, mark it as an accepted answer or comment why it did not work so we can all learn from this experience.

Answer (score 0):

The Dreamweaver design view sucks, it usually never gives an accurate representation of how things look in a real browser.

As an alternative and a helpful answer to your issues you can try the live view from dreamweaver that was implemented after CS5.

### Here is a video explaining how to set it up.

http://tv.adobe.com/watch/creating-time/dreamweavers-live-view-helps-you-save-time/

As a final note, try not to use the design view and tey to get more into the code... once you get used to it you can read the code and visualize almost exactly (usually always better than design view) how things look. So please do not trust design view in dreamweaver for development.